# Youtube asking to update Flash Player?

Tags: youtube, flash, internet-explorer-8

My friend has IE8. Everytime he opens his IE8 browser to visit youtube.com, this site asks him to update Adobe Flash to the newest version.

We uninstall it, reinstall it, reboot windows, installed IE9, but nothing happens: Youtube keeps on showing the same message about Flash Player.

The lastest version is Flash Player 10.3.181.26.

We have the same Windows 7, with same browser and same Flash Player version.

What can be wrong?

PS: Google Chrome shows flash player just fine.

Comment: Have you just tried updating rather than uninstalling and reinstalling? It sounds like IE has just got itself confused over the version.

Comment: Also is this just a problem when you visit YouTube? Do other video sites exhibit the same problem?

Comment: Hmm, there was no update message. When you click on Youtube link to update, it takes you to the site to download flash player again. It seems flash is not working on any site.

Comment: I were facing the same problem on youtube but i just go to update the flash player and downloaded the latest version and its working fine now and try to install the plugins of flash player too even I m using version 10.3.181.14 and working very fine.

Comment: I would assume the Flash plugin is disabled, so YouTube can't actually use it and therefore recommends you install it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to turn off activex filtering (from the small "not allowed" circle next to the refresh symbol)

good luck

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please be aware that one line answers a commonly frowned upon :( please expand on your answer to how it resolved the problem being faced in original question